# Visual Basic Compiler (vbc.exe) Using-up All System Memory (RAM & Virtual)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, compiler-errors, roslyn

I have an asp.net web application using VB in Visual Studio 2019. The project builds compiles and runs fine. We publish the files and drop them in the www root folder, works great.

We have one aspx file that started to get really big. It's over 5,000 lines now, 423kb.
This would work when hitting the aspx compiled, but would choke the roselyn compiler when accessing the published aspx.

*BC31498: Length of String constant exceeds current memory limit. Try splitting the string into multiple constants.*


We removed the rosyln compiler from the bin, and the reference in the web.config. This caused .NET to use C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe to compile it, we would get a slow down and it would then work, and the server would come back up. It had to build and cache the files I assume.

ANYWAY, the page is bigger now, and the published page will not load. We get the following error.

*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe failed with the following error.*

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: The compiler failed with error code -2147023441.

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

﻿c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /t:library /utf8output......

Can you not have large aspx files? Too many div tags?
I cleared the temp folder in the .net framework folder. There is no .NET version mismatch. Published code also works fine on a non production machine with MUCH more RAM(48GB).

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/40820) issue in roslyn. The native compiler (the one coming from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319) can handle slightly larger strings, but the issue is the same. The string literal that you are using is too big for the compiler to compile. My recommendation to you is to use resource files (.resx) instead of string literals. This should allow your page to be any size.

Comment: Which string literal is too big? The entire aspx as a string?
Why does it work, published, on a machine with 48GB RAM? Thank you!

Comment: I can't tell you which string literal is too big without seeing your code. Do you not have large string literals in the page?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. We don't have any strings within quotes larger than 500 characters per say, but there are alot. We use knockout.js so there are ton's of databind="blah blah blah". I will ping you on LinkedIn, if you would like to look at the code.